# Is there a way to load a new popup on a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I was wondering if there was way to load the new popup in a chrome extension, I changed the chrome popup using `chrome.action.setPopup({ popup: 'nextpage.html' })`. However to see the new popup i have to click on the extension badge. I was wondering if there was a way to make chrome display the new popup straight away.

Comment: location.href = 'nextpage.html' in your current popup script.